The convegence of the arithmetic mean of the bounded non-negative sequence and its square
This is from my homework.
How to construct a bounded non-negative sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_1^2+a_2^2+ \dots a_n^2\over n}$$exists,but$${a_1+a_2+ \dots a_n\over n}$$is divergent.
First,$\{a_n\}$ should be divergent.If not,using O'stolz,we know that
both of them are convergent.
I conjecture a sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfying $a_{3n+3}^2={a_{3n+2}^2+a_{3n+1}^2\over 2}$ may be what I want.But I'm not sure.
Please give me some ideas or hints.

Try $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$

@NagaSaiPrajith Why is that a valid example? The second sequence tends to $0$.

No solution: $AM \leq QM$ since $AM$ diverges by comparison test $QM$ diverges. Hence $A \leq QM$ for $N \leq n$ which means $A^2 \leq QM^2$ for large $A$

Your statement is not true,because it may be not monotonous.

Your question is interesting. Could you extend your post adding a context ? Perhaps you have your own thoughts ?  The extended question could be re-opened.

I find that ${a_n}$ should be divergent.
